# Wrong inventor server version when trying to use Inventor+2022

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

Just getting into Forge world with "ForgeSample" Inventor example. Fascinating indeed.
Just noticed than when selecting Engine as  Autodesk.Inventor+2022, it is still launching Inventor Server 2020.3, when WorkItem is started.
I made model also in 2020 (works), and 2021 (does not work).
/matti

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about this sample? https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/modifymodels

If you already set up the **activity** with a given **Inventor Server** version, then change in the dropdown afterwards to a different version then it won't modify what the **activity** is using - see https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.designautomation/blob/nodejs/routes/DesignAutomation.js#L374

In the case of the sample, you have the option to clear your account inside the "Configure" dialog and do the setup again.

You can also use a utility like this to make sure that the **activity** is using the correct **Inventor Server** version: https://da-manager.autodesk.io/

[image]